# When using a for loop range with an increment of three, why does the first number 'group' to itself?

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

We are using the following book in a class I am TA-ing for:
[craftbuzzcoder](https://craft.buzzcoder.com/?lesson=python).
In *Part 3 (Loop)*, section *Wall & cube*, they have a challenge of creating an inverted pyramid.

The following is the book solution:

```
for j in range(0,10,3): 
    for i in range (-j, j+1, 3):
        for k in range(-j, j+1, 3):
            game.set_block(Position(i, j+1, k), 45)
```

From what I can tell, it seems to be that the first number in the sequence of the respective range (for example, the *y-axis/j* variable) is counted/grouped by itself rather than by the increment of 3.

Why is this?

**tl;dr**
I would expect it to increment like this:
[image]

Instead it seems to be increment like this:
[image]

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand how python range works and this will become easier for you.

> range(start, stop[, step])
>
> **start** is from where you want to start the iteration
>
> **stop** is at where you want to stop the iteration, exclusive
>
> **step** means how much you want to add to start
>
> but there is a small catch with this, if step is positive, the last element is the largest start + i * step less than stop; if step is negative, the last element is the smallest start + i * step greater than stop. step must not be zero and step defaults to 1

So in your case it is working like -

```
for j in range(0,10,3):
    print j
```

We get -

```
j = 0 -> add 3, j becomes 3 -> add 3, j becomes 6 -> add 3, j becomes 9, add 3, j becomes 12  which is greater than stop -> exit
```

More [examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) of range.

Comment: This makes perfect sense now! Thank you so much for your help and clear example!

Answer (score 2):

The `step` part of the range is applied *after* each value is yielded. The first thing in `range(0,10)` is `0`, then you add `3` to get `3`, then `6`, etc. You are not choosing how large the groups are -- just how much the value is incremented each step.

Comment: Oooooohh thank you so much this makes perfect sense thank you!